# Google sheets script to add new data to a dropdown box data range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im looking for a script that will automatically update a data range for drop down lists when a new value is used. my scripting knowledge is very limited and ive been working and playing around with scripts that seem to provide a similar result but none of them work in the way that i want

Example:

Sheet 1, column B2:B has drop down boxes from a data range 'Data Sheet'!C2C

When i type my own data into sheet one column B i want to check if it already exists in the data range or add it if it doesnt exist so that it can be easily used again next time it occurs.

i know i can use the =Query function which is great and ive combined it with other fuctions to check if it already eixists. The problem is once they are removed from Sheet 1 it removes them from the list and i want a more permanent Data range

Comment: Try using the onEdit trigger

Comment: Use of indeterminate ranges like `B2:B` is Not a good idea in apps script.  Use `sheet.getLastRow()` if you can or use `startrow,startcolumn,number of rows,number of columns`